# JSP- Grouping rows of database with unique field name?

Tags: html, sql, database, jsp

I'm using SQL queries in JSP and I'm looking to group the rows of my database with a unique field. Please see example below.

```
My current query output:
Custid   Value  Quantity
10001     200      5
10001     300      1
10002     200      3
10002     100      4
10002     300      2
```

---

```
What I'm trying to achieve:
Custid   Value  Quantity
10001     200      5
          300      1
10002     200      3
          100      4
          300      2
```

---

I have using using the following code, but have only managed to order the field, I can get it to work with one field (custid), but when I add in the other two (value, Quantity). I'm getting errors. Tried using GROUP BY, ORDER BY and DISTINCT, can't get it to work.
Please see code:

```
 <sql:query dataSource="${bookdB}" var="result">
  SELECT * FROM Invoice
  ORDER BY cust_id AND
  GROUP BY cust_id;
 </sql:query>


  <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
   <tr>
    <td><i><c:out value="${row.cust_id}"/></i></td>
    <td><font color="black"><c:out value="${row.value}"/></font></td>
    <td><font color="black"><c:out value="${row.quantity}"/></font></td>
   </tr>
  </c:forEach>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated with MS Access syntax:

```
select iif((value = grp_value and quantity = grp_quantity),cust_id,'') as cust_id
       value,
       quantity
  from (select x.*, grp.value as grp_value, grp.quantity as grp_quantity
          from invoice x
          join invoice grp
            on x.cust_id = grp.cust_id
         where grp.value = (select min(y.value)
                              from invoice y
                             where y.cust_id = x.cust_id)
           and grp.quantity = (select min(y.quantity)
                                 from invoice y
                                where y.cust_id = x.cust_id
                                  and y.value = grp.value)
         order by x.cust_id, x.value, x.quantity) x
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added your code, but got the following error. ": [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'case when value = grp_value and quantity = grp_quantity then cust_id else null end'.". Any ideas???

Comment: @ConorCaslin That syntax is compatible with most databases (mysql, Oracle, sql server, etc.) but not Microsoft Access. In Access you would use an IIF statement rather than a case statement, but I'm not 100% familiar with the syntax. I'll edit in a sec when I look it up.

Comment: New error. "[Microsoft Access Driver] The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect".  I thought value was the problem so I changed value to value1, but still the same error.

Comment: @ConorCaslin Do you actually have a column named "value"? If it's named something else change every instance of "value" in the sql to the name of the field. If you do have a field named "value", I'd rename it to something else, otherwise enclosing it in brackets would solve the problem.

Comment: @ConorCaslin I didn't see that you already mentioned trying changing the column, can you just double check to see all of the sql was changed to reflect the new field name

Comment: Yeah, I had a field called value. when I seen the error saying reserve word I thought that might be the problem but it wasn't. I've renamed value and added the changes to all your sql query. Still getting the same error though.

Comment: I'll mess around with it for a bit and see if I can get it working. Thanks for all your help man. Appreciate your time.

Comment: I solved that error, the statement was missing a comma after cust_id. But now I'm getting a "Syntax error in FROM clause".